# The Chessboard Editor at Apronus.com --- Is it any good?

Tags: online-chess, pgn

I am the webmaster of the online chessboard editor at http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php. I spend about one week each year on maintaining this utility but I never get to work seriously on it. I wonder if perhaps this has some potential that should be exploited.

The specific questions that I want to ask here:

1. Is it useful for playing correspondence games by email?
2. Is it useful for posting static diagrams (just one position image) in blogs and forums?
3. Is it useful for posting dynamic diagrams (showing games or parts of games)?
4. Is it useful for playing against computer from a set up position?
5. Is it useful for posting chess puzzles?

Comment: While I appreciate the relevance of the software to users of this site, "Please rate my software" seems off-topic.

Comment: The question is probably most suited among the users of your editor. By asking it here some of us may feel compelled to try it and test it even though we have never used it.

Comment: I have written and published a chess book but I would love to use Apronus to animate my diagrams in a new version. Is this allowed, if it becomes a commercial proposition, or can I apply to use the site commercially. It seems great as I can use the chess app in OpenOffice rather than in a Blog or website. Regards,
Paul Wiseman

Comment: Use the email address on the homepage of Apronus.com to inquire about a license for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it useful for playing correspondence games by email?

I have never tried it.

> Is it useful for posting static diagrams (just one position image) in blogs and forums?

Do you mean something like [this](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch/280#280)? I use it to generate FEN when posting answers here, all the time.

> Is it useful for posting dynamic diagrams (showing games or parts of games)?

Again, I generate the FEN on Apronus, but I post moves here myself. I have never tried to create "a game" and then simply copy/paste it here. If you can show me how, I could try it out and report my results.

> Is it useful for playing against computer from a set up position?

I did generate FEN on Apronus and successfully loaded it into Fritz.

> Is it useful for posting chess puzzles?

Again, it does a good job in generating the FEN, so I can post here any diagram I want.

> The Chessboard Editor at Apronus.com — Is it any good?

Serves me very well so far. I just don't know how to generate "games" and "dynamic diagrams" as you have suggested. That would be an awesome feature to posses, it would save me so much time!

If you need any help or you have followup questions, leave a comment.

Best regards.

Comment: You seem to be aware of only one functionality that is available out of many. You just generate a FEN from a set up position but you can make a diagram of one position, an animated diagram showing a game or a fragment, generate a link that contains a game or a fragment to share through email, blog or forum. For example, http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php?m=f3_e6_g4_Qh4M . The buttons [diagram] and [(animated) diagram] are perhaps not so easy to see. You can also start a Java applet to play from a set up position.

Answer (score 1):

A short and partial answer based on recent use by your editor is:

> Is it useful for posting static diagrams (just one position image) in blogs and forums?

Yes, yes it is, and quite a bit. It works nicely and the design is timeless.

> Is it useful for posting dynamic diagrams (showing games or parts of games)?

Indeed, for showing full games with no interaction with the user, the dynamic diagrams work perfectly.

> Is it useful for posting chess puzzles?

The same answer to the first question is valid, as static diagrams may very well in some articles be problems.

I think the editor is quite good for a free one, and I will encourage it's use among my students. If your could improve the quality of the pieces though, that would be nice, as they appear to be quite pixelated.

Comment: I wonder if it is useful for posting puzzles not just as static diagrams. There's an option to have the user play the puzzle against computer. Another option is to display the solution as an embedded diagram that can be navigated by the user.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful for making gifs that shows some variations from the game.
I use those to explore endgames. (They're good because I don't need any chess viewer to use them, just smth to view gif.)

Sadly animated gifs doesn't work if <del>one of the board sizes is bigger than 8</del> dimensions are 16*16. :( It's kinda important because of FICGS chess variations Big Chess.